# Troubles installing Apache2 from source Redhat 6

Tags: apache

I am trying to install the most current Apache version. I ran configure:

```
 ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache --enable-so --with-pcre=../pcre2-10.00/pcre2-config
```

But I then got this error message:

> util_pcre.c:49:18: error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
>        util_pcre.c: In Function 'ap_regfree':
>        util_pcre.c:104: error: 'pcre_free' undeclared (first use in this function)
>        util_pcre.c:104: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
>        util_pcre.c:104: error: for each function it appears in.)....

I read that I would need to have gcc installed. And I have verified that gcc is installed. Do I need to declare it somewhere in the ./configure command? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Try to install pcre devel

```
yum install pcre-devel
```

and then run your previous code without pcre part

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache --enable-so
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

As at version 2.4.25 of Apache it doesn't appear that you can compile with pcre2. You can either do what Milos Miskone Sretin suggests and use yum to install the pcre development headers or if you want to potentially have multiple versions of pcre then you have to compile and install pcre 8.40 and link against it instead.

Assuming you have installed pcre 8.40 into `/usr/local/apps/pcre/8.40` then

`./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache --enable-so --with-pcre=/usr/local/apps/pcre/8.40`

Answer (score 0):

seems you are using pcre2 instead of pcre. Download and re-compile with PCRE.

because PCRE2 is the name used for a revised API for the PCRE library.